# Debug Assertion Failed only with some cases? C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm very new to C++, and I was wondering why my code fails only in some cases. Whenever N > 3, Debug Assertion Failed comes up? I was pretty sure that I only called upon existing vector values. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N, input, sum=0;
    vector <int> tasks;

    cin >> N;
    for (int a = 0; a <= N-1 ; a++){
        cin >> input;
        tasks.push_back(input);
    }

    sort(tasks.begin(), tasks.end());

    if(N%2==0){
        for (int i = 0; i<=N/2-1; i++) {
            sum += 2 * tasks.front()*tasks.back();
            tasks.erase(tasks.begin(), tasks.end());
        }
    }
    else {
        sum += tasks[(N + 1) / 2-1] * tasks[(N + 1) / 2-1];
        tasks.erase(tasks.begin()+(N-1)/2);

        for (int i = 0; i <= (N-2) / 2; i++) {
            sum = sum + 2*tasks.front()*tasks.back();
            tasks.erase(tasks.begin(), tasks.end());
        }
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Q: Please update your post with the *EXACT* message.  Q: What compiler are you using?  Q:

Comment: *I was pretty sure* -- So I guess you didn't actually debug your code.

Comment: The debugging didn't catch it. It was a problem with my vector.erase, where I put them on one line instead of 2.

Comment: @DavidWu Are you using the debugger that comes with Visual Studio (I am assuming this due to the error message)?  The code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e535cb8d47643e2f) when run under Visual Studio immediately shows that `tasks` is empty on the very first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was using.

Comment: tasks.erase(tasks.begin(), tasks.end()); wiped out the vector if N>3, because then the loop would run again. I've fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your call to tasks.erase(tasks.begin(), tasks.end()). It's deleting all elements in the vector.

Comment: Oh, I see! Should I make it 2 separate lines to delete the starting and ending elements by themselves?